# How to access Stage Variables of API Gateway from Postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda with multiple versions and API Gateway is created with Stagevariables pointing the alias name.

If executed within AWS console by substituing the different alias name for Stage Variable, the output is accurate, but if executing the same from postman, it fails.

Executing something like this from Postman:

```
https://123-execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/StageName/LambdaFunctionName?variable=XYZ
```

**Note: Each Alias version has a different output**

Any leads on this would be helpful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can not set *Stage Variables* from Postman. They are part of the API Gateway and not part of any HTTP standard.

Comment: i'm not setting the Stage Variabls from Postman, wanted to access the Stage Variables from Postman/Rest call so that external access is going to be correct Alias function